# IllegalStateException No view found forFragment while replacing fragment in activity

Tags: java, android, fragment, containers, illegalstateexception

I am trying to make an activity with two fragments displaying one after another. Here below is my activity and fragment code.

MainActivity

```
public class DeliveryActivity extends BaseActivity {

private static final String ROOT_FRAG = "root_fragment";

@Override
protected int layoutRes() {
    return R.layout.activity_delivery;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (savedInstanceState == null)

    getSupportFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction().add(R.id.fl_container,
                new DeliveryListFragment())
    .addToBackStack(ROOT_FRAG).commit();
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}

public void navigateToDetailsScreen() {
             getSupportFragmentManager()
             .beginTransaction()
             .replace(R.id.fl_container,
             new DeliveryDetailFragment()).commit();
}
```

}

BaseActivity.java

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends DaggerAppCompatActivity {

@LayoutRes
protected abstract int layoutRes();

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(layoutRes());
}
```

}

activity_delivery.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/fl_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

While I am adding the first fragment the container is fine and allow to add but when I am trying to replace fragment (Second fragment) then it's giving me below error.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f08004c (com.assessment.project:id/fl_container) for fragment SecondFragment{15674f3 #2 id=0x7f08004c}
```

Comment: From where you are calling `#navigateToDetailsScreen()`?

Answer (score 0):

I think your function should be like this

```
public void navigateToDetailsScreen(View view) {
             getSupportFragmentManager()
             .beginTransaction()
             .replace(R.id.fl_container,
             new DeliveryDetailFragment()).commit();
}
```

Comment: Why you think this ? And why unused argument `View view`?

Comment: If he using 'onClick'  as trigger from xml file he must using view as params in his method even though it is unused, or it will produce crash and the name of that crash is IllegalStateException